# Cannot centre Button variant

Tags: css, reactjs

I am working on a React [project](https://morning-dusk-53803.herokuapp.com/) and I am trying to centre my Button variant to the centre of the home screen. However, I can’t seem to do so. Does anyone have any idea how to do so?

My code

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Fancyline from "./Fancylines";
import lock from "./lock.png";
import { Typography, Button, Card, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import homepage1 from "./homepage1.png";



function Login() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        minHeight: "100vh",
        backgroundImage: `url(${homepage1})`,
        backgroundPosition: "center",
        backgroundSize: "cover"
      }}>
    <div style={{
      textAlign:"center",
      verticalAlign:"bottom",
      bottom:"0px"
    }}>
      <Link to="/Language">
        <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" size="large">
          CONTINUE
        </Button>
      </Link>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see in your code that you are using Material-ui. To achieve what you are asking for, simply use Material-ui Grid component with following props.

```
<Grid
  container
  direction="row"
  justify="center"
  alignItems="center"
>
```

the complete code will look like this:-

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Fancyline from "./Fancylines";
import lock from "./lock.png";
import { Typography, Button, Card, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import homepage1 from "./homepage1.png";



function Login() {
  return (
    <Grid 
      container
      direction="row"
      justify="center"
      alignItems="center"
    >
      <Link to="/Language">
        <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" size="large">
          CONTINUE
        </Button>
      </Link>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox for your container:

```
function Login() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        minHeight: "100vh",
        backgroundImage: `url(${homepage1})`,
        backgroundPosition: "center",
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        display: 'flex';               // Flexbox styling here
        flexDirection: 'column';
        justifyContent: 'center';
      }}>
    <div style={{
      textAlign:"center",
      verticalAlign:"bottom",
      bottom:"0px"
    }}>
      <Link to="/Language">
        <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" size="large">
          CONTINUE
        </Button>
      </Link>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css `display: flex`, `align-items: center` & `justify-content: center`

**[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-bartik-xezn5)**

```
function Login() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        minHeight: "100vh",
        backgroundImage: `url(${homepage1})`,
        backgroundPosition: "center",
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent:"center",
        alignItems:"center"
      }}>
    <div style={{
      textAlign:"center",
      verticalAlign:"bottom",
      bottom:"0px"
    }}>
      <Link to="/Language">
        <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" size="large">
          CONTINUE
        </Button>
      </Link>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use absolute position:

```
<Button variant="contained" color="secondary" size="large"
           style={{position:"absolute,
           top:"50%",left:"50%",
           transform:"translate(-50%,-50%)"
             }}>
              CONTINUE
            </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
function Login() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        minHeight: "100vh",
        backgroundImage: `url(${homepage1})`,
        backgroundPosition: "center",
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }}>
    <div style={{
      textAlign:"center",
      verticalAlign:"bottom",
      bottom:"0px"
    }}>
      <Link to="/Language">
        <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" size="large">
          CONTINUE
        </Button>
      </Link>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

just add this in you parent `div`.

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```